# Call to a member function AddAddress() on null

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to create a pop-up form for suggestions that will email me whenever somebody hits submit.  I keep getting an error message stating "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function AddAddress() on null"  here is my php file:

```
<?PHP

require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");

$formproc = new FGContactForm();
$myemail="johndoe@gmail.com";

$formproc->AddRecipient($myemail); //<<---Put your email address here




$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('CnRrspl1FyEylUj');


if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
if($formproc->ProcessForm())
{
     $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
}
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
   <title>Contact us</title>
   <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="contact.css" />
   <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Form Code Start -->
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Contact us</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
 <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
 <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
 <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
 <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
 <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
 <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
 <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
 <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
 <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
</div>


<div class='container'>
 <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[

 var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactus");
 frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
 frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
 frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");

 frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address");

 frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please provide a valid email address");

 frmvalidator.addValidation("message","maxlen=2048","The message is too long!(more than 2KB!)");

// ]]>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
and here is the php script to actually send the mail:
```

```
<?PHP

require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

/*
Interface to Captcha handler
*/
class FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    function Validate() { return false;}
    function GetError(){ return '';}
}

class FGContactForm
{
    var $receipients;
    var $errors;
    var $error_message;
    var $name;
    var $email;
    var $message;
    var $from_address;
    var $form_random_key;
    var $conditional_field;
    var $arr_conditional_receipients;
    var $fileupload_fields;
    var $captcha_handler;

    var $mailer;

    function FGContactForm()
    {
        $this->receipients = array();
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
        $this->conditional_field='';
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
        $this->fileupload_fields=array();

        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    }

    function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
    {
        $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
        session_start();
    }

    function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
    {
        print $email;
        print $name;
        $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
    }

    function SetFromAddress($from)
    {
        $this->from_address = $from;
    }
    function SetFormRandomKey($key)
    {
        $this->form_random_key = $key;
    }
    function GetSpamTrapInputName()
    {
        return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->GetKey());
    }
    function SafeDisplay($value_name)
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
        {
            return'';
        }
        return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
    }
    function GetFormIDInputName()
    {
        $rand = md5('TygshRt'.$this->GetKey());

        $rand = substr($rand,0,20);
        return 'id'.$rand;
    }


    function GetFormIDInputValue()
    {
        return md5('jhgahTsajhg'.$this->GetKey());
    }

    function SetConditionalField($field)
    {
        $this->conditional_field = $field;
    }
    function AddConditionalReceipent($value,$email)
    {
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients[$value] =  $email;
    }

    function AddFileUploadField($file_field_name,$accepted_types,$max_size)
    {

        $this->fileupload_fields[] =
            array("name"=>$file_field_name,
            "file_types"=>$accepted_types,
            "maxsize"=>$max_size);
    }

    function ProcessForm()
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
        {
           return false;
        }
        if(!$this->Validate())
        {
            $this->error_message = implode('<br/>',$this->errors);
            return false;
        }
        $this->CollectData();

        $ret = $this->SendFormSubmission();

        return $ret;
    }

    function RedirectToURL($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

    function GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $this->error_message;
    }
    function GetSelfScript()
    {
        return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    function GetName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    function GetEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    function GetMessage()
    {
        return htmlentities($this->message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    }

/*--------  Private (Internal) Functions -------- */


    function SendFormSubmission()
    {
        $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();

        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
        
        $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact form submission from $this->name";

        $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

        $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;

        $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);

        $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();

        $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
        $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
        $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);

        $this->AttachFiles();

        if(!$this->mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->add_error("Failed sending email!");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function CollectConditionalReceipients()
    {
        if(count($this->arr_conditional_receipients)>0 &&
          !empty($this->conditional_field) &&
          !empty($_POST[$this->conditional_field]))
        {
            foreach($this->arr_conditional_receipients as $condn => $rec)
            {
                if(strcasecmp($condn,$_POST[$this->conditional_field])==0 &&
                !empty($rec))
                {
                    $this->AddRecipient($rec);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    Internal variables, that you donot want to appear in the email
    Add those variables in this array.
    */
    function IsInternalVariable($varname)
    {
        $arr_interanl_vars = array('scaptcha',
                            'submitted',
                            $this->GetSpamTrapInputName(),
                            $this->GetFormIDInputName()
                            );
        if(in_array($varname,$arr_interanl_vars))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function FormSubmissionToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(!$this->IsInternalVariable($key))
            {
                $value = htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
                $value = nl2br($value);
                $key = ucfirst($key);
                $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>$key :</div><div class='value'>$value </div>\n";
            }
        }
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upload_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upload_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }        
            
            $filename = basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>File upload '$field_name' :</div><div class='value'>$filename </div>\n";
        }
        return $ret_str;
    }

    function ExtraInfoToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $ret_str = "<div class='label'>IP address of the submitter:</div><div class='value'>$ip</div>\n";

        return $ret_str;
    }

    function GetMailStyle()
    {
        $retstr = "\n<style>".
        "body,.label,.value { font-family:Arial,Verdana; } ".
        ".label {font-weight:bold; margin-top:5px; font-size:1em; color:#333;} ".
        ".value {margin-bottom:15px;font-size:0.8em;padding-left:5px;} ".
        "</style>\n";

        return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLHeaderPart()
    {
         $retstr = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">'."\n".
                   '<html><head><title></title>'.
                   '<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
         $retstr .= $this->GetMailStyle();
         $retstr .= '</head><body>';
         return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLFooterPart()
    {
        $retstr ='</body></html>';
        return $retstr ;
    }
    function ComposeFormtoEmail()
    {
        $header = $this->GetHTMLHeaderPart();
        $formsubmission = $this->FormSubmissionToMail();
        $extra_info = $this->ExtraInfoToMail();
        $footer = $this->GetHTMLFooterPart();

        $message = $header."Submission from 'contact us' form:<p>$formsubmission</p><hr/>$extra_info".$footer;

        return $message;
    }

    function AttachFiles()
    {
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            $filename =basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $this->mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES[$field_name]["tmp_name"],$filename);
        }
    }

    function GetFromAddress()
    {
        if(!empty($this->from_address))
        {
            return $this->from_address;
        }

        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        $from ="nobody@$host";
        return $from;
    }

    function Validate()
    {
        $ret = true;
        //security validations
        if(empty($_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()]) ||
          $_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()] != $this->GetFormIDInputValue() )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 1 failed");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //This is a hidden input field. Humans won't fill this field.
        if(!empty($_POST[$this->GetSpamTrapInputName()]) )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 2 failed");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //name validations
        if(empty($_POST['name']))
        {
            $this->add_error("Please provide your name");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['name'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error("Name is too big!");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //email validations
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error("Please provide your email address");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['email'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error("Email address is too big!");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(!$this->validate_email($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error("Please provide a valid email address");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //message validaions
        if(strlen($_POST['message'])>2048)
        {
            $this->add_error("Message is too big!");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //captcha validaions
        if(isset($this->captcha_handler))
        {
            if(!$this->captcha_handler->Validate())
            {
                $this->add_error($this->captcha_handler->GetError());
                $ret = false;
            }
        }
        //file upload validations
        if(!empty($this->fileupload_fields))
        {
         if(!$this->ValidateFileUploads())
         {
            $ret = false;
         }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes)
    {
        $ret=true;
        $info = pathinfo($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
        $extn = $info['extension'];
        $extn = strtolower($extn);

        $arr_valid_filetypes= explode(',',$valid_filetypes);
        if(!in_array($extn,$arr_valid_filetypes))
        {
            $this->add_error("Valid file types are: $valid_filetypes");
            $ret=false;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileSize($field_name,$max_size)
    {
        $size_of_uploaded_file =
                $_FILES[$field_name]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs
        if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_size)
        {
            $this->add_error("The file is too big. File size should be less than $max_size KB");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
    {
        if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function ValidateFileUploads()
    {
        $ret=true;
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];

            $valid_filetypes = $upld_field["file_types"];
            
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if($_FILES[$field_name]["error"] != 0)
            {
                $this->add_error("Error in file upload; Error code:".$_FILES[$field_name]["error"]);
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($valid_filetypes) &&
             !$this->ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes))
            {
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($upld_field["maxsize"]) &&
            $upld_field["maxsize"]>0)
            {
                if(!$this->ValidateFileSize($field_name,$upld_field["maxsize"]))
                {
                    $ret=false;
                }
            }

        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function StripSlashes($str)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    /*
    Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
    data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
    if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
    */
    function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
    {
        $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

        if($remove_nl)
        {
            $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
                '/(\r+)/i',
                '/(\t+)/i',
                '/(%0A+)/i',
                '/(%0D+)/i',
                '/(%08+)/i',
                '/(%09+)/i'
                );
            $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    /*Collects clean data from the $_POST array and keeps in internal variables.*/
    function CollectData()
    {
        $this->name = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
        $this->email = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);

        /*newline is OK in the message.*/
        $this->message = $this->StripSlashes($_POST['message']);
    }

    function add_error($error)
    {
        array_push($this->errors,$error);
    }
    function validate_email($email)
    {
        return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email);
    }

    function GetKey()
    {
        return $this->form_random_key.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

}

?>
```

Here is the full error. When I call the $email variable in the second file, it can display my email perfectly, and it can pull the email into the FGContactForm, so i'm not really sure what the problem is.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function AddAddress() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\staff\ContactForm\include\fgcontactform.php:72 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\staff\ContactForm\contactform.php(16): FGContactForm->AddRecipient('johndoe@g...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\staff\ContactForm\include\fgcontactform.php on line 72

Comment: `function FGContactForm` in the class `FGContactForm` is not being called, because using same-named functions as constructors has been removed since PHP 5.5.3. This means that `$this->mailer` has not been initialized. Change that function to `function __construct()`

Comment: I appreciate the quick response and I went ahead and changed it, however, it didn't stop the aforementioned error from occurring.

Comment: Add an echo/log line in the constructor function to make sure it's being called. Also make sure you're using 2 underscores in the function name

Comment: I'm seeing that actually a lot of the functions in this code have been deprecated and I feel like i'm beating a dead horse. So I have to start fresh but either way, thank you for the help, greatly appreciated!